# Windows CHM file only displays images for Administrator

Tags: windows, images, administrator, chm, limited-user-account

I installed some software on my Windows 2000 machine.  The software has a user manual in .CHM format.  When I view the manual while logged in as Administrator, everything looks fine.  The manual has images embedded in it and they are all displayed.

But when I try to view the manual while logged in as a limited-user, none of the images get displayed.  Each image is replaced by an empty box with a red X in the corner.

I emailed the developer of the software about this and their reply contained a non-answer.

Why is a limited-user unable to view the embedded images in the CHM file?

Comment: This has something to do with Windows 2000, because I installed the software on a Windows XP machine, and the limited-user account on that machine had no problems with the CHM file.

Comment: I don't think this is limited to Windows 2k, I had this problem in Windows 7:  http://superuser.com/questions/1062259/what-can-cause-images-to-not-show-in-html-help-chm-files-if-uac-is-enabled