# What can cause images to not show in HTML Help (chm files) if UAC is Enabled?

Tags: windows-7, uac, chm

On a computer running Windows 7 Embedded Standard (SP1), 64 bit, I am not able to view images in any chm files unless UAC is turned completely off.

All of the images are replaced with a small black and white box with an "X" in it.

Things I've tried:

- If I transfer the chm files to a different Windows 7 Embedded computer running the exact same version of IE (11.0.9600.18230), the chm files work perfectly, even if UAC is set to "Always Notify".
- None of these chm files come from the internet.
- [No paths to the chm files has a # in it. Even if I copy it to the desktop or C:\ (my user folder is on the D:) I still don't see images.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823166/chm-file-unreadble-if-saved-to-hdd)
- [Internet Explorer is set to display images](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-winapps/blank-boxes-at-the-place-of-pictures-in-compiled/316dcff8-308c-418e-a3b9-7cb5d5f243e3?auth=1]This%20issue%20on%20answers.microsoft.com)
- [There's no "Unblock" button in the properties shown for any chm file](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Jan/11/Problems-with-opening-CHM-Help-files-from-Network-or-Internet)
- [This help file is not on a network drive, and I'm not running Windows XP, but I tried this `ItssRestrictions` registry fix anyway. I tried setting it to 1, then I set it to the least restrictive setting (4), no effect.](http://helpscribble.com/chmnetwork.html)
- I have tried running regsvr32 to register hhctrl.ocx, itss.dll, and itircl.dll.
- If I view the chm file using SumatraPDF, it works perfectly, even as a non-administrator when UAC is enabled.
- If I load the help file by running hh.exe from command line as administrator, images work properly. Images don't load if hh is run by a normal user.
- If I open the chm file in 7-zip and extract all of the html documents and open them in IE11, the images work even if UAC is enabled.
- Internet explorer settings for "Trusted sites" is set to "Low", and I have added "localhost", "127.0.0.1", and the computer's name as trusted sites.
- [MJ's help report for the working computer](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/808e672a96d7c2aafe41ef26f7b7c99e)
- [MJ's help report for the non-working computer](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/16b6f9bc4f32e332d64fcbbacad175d9)

Is there anything else I could try to narrow down the possible causes of this problem?

Are there any other security settings that can affect chm files?

Other related questions

- [Windows CHM file only displays images for Administrator (Windows 2000)](https://superuser.com/questions/571410/windows-chm-file-only-displays-images-for-administrator?rq=1) (no answer)

Comment: What level is UAC set to when it causes problems?

Comment: I just ran through every UAC setting (with a reboot between each change), images only show if UAC is turned completely off.

Comment: Did you try to go one step back to IE10? See: [How to downgrade from Internet Explorer 11 to Internet Explorer 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043971/how-to-downgrade-from-internet-explorer-11-to-internet-explorer-10)

Comment: Use MJ’s Help Diagnostics to ensure (again) that all the help viewer components are properly installed and registered. Download from http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/mj-s-diagnostics

Comment: @help-info.de Thanks. I recently noticed that another Windows Embedded 7 PC has no trouble with opening chm files, the only difference I could find between the PC that works, and the PC that doesn't work, is that the IE versions are slightly different. The working PC is running 11.0.9600.17689 and the non-working PC is running 11.0.9600.16521....

Comment: ... I'll try updating IE on the non-working box but if that small difference in IE versions is enough to break HTML Help I'd be a little concerned: These boxes are not typically connected to the internet and having a Windows image that can reliably open chm files is important.

Comment: really annoying - I hope you can fix it.

Comment: Updating IE to 11.0.9600.18230 on the non-working PC did not seem to have any effect, at this point I'm seriously considering just re-installing Windows on that PC

Comment: I mentioned this question in Root Access:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32687164#32687164

Comment: Also, one thing I wanted to mention regarding chm is a dead format, [it's actively being used](http://www.rockwellautomation.com/rockwellsoftware/products/rslogix.page) [in new products](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/93842624/service-pack-4-for-step-7-v5-5-and-step-7-professional-2010?dti=0&lc=en-WW) [in more places](https://www.kepware.com/en-us/products/kepserverex/) [then you may think](http://www.matrox.com/imaging/en/products/software/mil/), Also, to the best of my knowledge Microsoft has never released a statement saying chm is obsolete or unsupported...

Comment: ... not supporting these old help formats would be a severe competitive disadvantage for us (in the industrial sector), `converting to pdf` would mean converting and maintaining our own set of docs for help manuals from many different companies (plus anticipating what our users might need), and it seems like it would violate copyright agreements. Also [doing that might break context sensitive help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408461/what-good-alternatives-to-chm-are-there-for-context-sensitive-help-documents-in).

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with an XP computer (not Seven) for years. I'm far from being a superuser so I managed to keep it this way for years!
But recently I had a "stupid" idea. Went and see in IE advanced config... (This is not my default browser).
The "show image" option was simply unchecked. I checked the box and guess what? It worked! I can see the image in CHM_help files again!
Maybe it can help...

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but Internet Options -> Advanced -> Multimedia -> Show Pictures is checked.

Comment: Thank you. This saved my time from reinstalling windows! I changed it in Internet Explorer 6 from Internet Options -> Advanced -> Multimedia -> Show Pictures and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In my case this was solved this by clearing the read-only attribute of the **INetCache** folder in Window's local Appdata folder. [Source](http://www.forum.freecommander.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=6943)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but never touched UAC.

There are apparently different levels of authentication for the HTMLHelp MaxAllowedZone registry. Most articles I read tell you to set the MaxAllowedZone to '1' which means that local machine zone and intranet zone are allowed but '4' allows access for 'all' zones.

For more info, read this article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/892675

This is how my registry looks (I wasn't sure it would work with the wild cards but it seems to work for me):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\ItssRestrictions]
"MaxAllowedZone"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\HTMLHelp\1.x\ItssRestrictions]
"UrlAllowList"="\\\\<network_path_root>;\\\\<network_path_root>\*;\\ies-inc.local;http://www.*;http://*;https://www.*;https://*;"
```

As an additional note, weirdly the "UrlAllowList" key was required to make this work on another PC but not my test one. It's probably not required at all but when I added it, it fixed the problem. The user may have not closed the original file or something like that. So just a consideration. I suggest try the least and test it, then add if needed. Once you confirm, you can deploy if needed. Good Luck!

P.S. Another method that worked was mapping the path to the network locally by using mklink /d (symbolic linking in Windows 7 or newer) but mapping a network drive letter (Z: for testing) did not work. Just food for thought and not really recommended. I also did not have to 'Unblock' any files and read probably all the same treads you did and no one had this solution which I thought was odd. Thanks.

Comment: I tested with URLAllowList, it didn't seem to have any effect, including after a reboot; MaxAllowedZone was already at 4. After that, just to try it I even added `*` and `*.*` temporarily to the end of URLAllowList. Thanks for the idea though. I'm not sure what you mean by the network symlink solution; this is on the D:\ of the computer (I've tried C:\ too), where D is a partition on the computer's hard disk; currently there is no network drive. Were you suggesting that the help file might work better if it resides on a network drive?

Comment: On windows from an elevated command prompt, use something like this (I use it all the time): mklink /d C:\<LocalPath> \\<UNC_Path\to\folder>